# Is there an ASRock RGB sync SDK?

Tags: sdk

Is there a way to programmatically control RGB lighting connected to an ASRock motherboard? I know Asus has an Aura SDK, but does ASRock also have one for their hardware?

If yes, where can I find it?

Comment: You can start here (if you didn't find any better way): https://github.com/dcerisano/RGB-LED-Motherboard-Header-Driver-App/issues/1

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'd like to integrate the ASRock RGB with my google assistant.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an sdk for ASRock polychrome. but you can link polychrome to Razer Chroma, which does have an sdk.

*image:* [Asrock device in Razer Chroma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0EOQ.png)

You'll need:

- The ASRock polychrome app specifically for your motherboard
- [Razer Chroma](https://dl.razerzone.com/drivers/Synapse3/win/RazerSynapseInstaller_V1.0.114.147.exe)
- [Razer Developers Page](https://developer.razer.com/works-with-chroma/download/)

You can turn on the link between Razer Chroma and ASRock Polychrome sync in the Polychrome app:
*image:* [Where to enable Razer Chroma sync in Polychrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seO2C.png)